# Visual C++ has only one thread working (OpenMP)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, openmp

I have this simple code for a multithreading application, but no matter the number of threads I pass it, it only executes with one thread. Initially, I thought this was a problem with my computer, but I tried on another and it also didn't work. Am I going anything wrong? I am using Visual Studio 2015 if that helps.

```
int th_id, nthreads;
#pragma omp parallel private(th_id) shared(nthreads) num_threads(3)
{
    th_id = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        cout << "Hello World from thread " << th_id << '\n';
    }
    #pragma omp barrier

    #pragma omp master
    {
        nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        cout << "There are " << nthreads << " threads" << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you activate OpenMP support in the project properties dialog? 
You can find it under "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language".